# ¿Cómo obtener el promedio más alto de un conjunto de promedios?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7W0b.png

Con la cual ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT AVG(NOTA)
FROM   CONTROL_ESCOLAR.NOTAS
GROUP BY NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO;
```

Mostrando así, el promedio de cada alumno registrado, pero lo que en realidad necesito es solo mostrar el alumno con el promedio más alto; ya lo logré realizar esto con la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT MAX(PROMEDIO)
FROM   (SELECT AVG(NOTA) AS PROMEDIO
        FROM   CONTROL_ESCOLAR.NOTAS
        GROUP BY NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO) AS FOO;
```

Sin embargo, a mi profesor no le pareció bien, por lo que me gustaría conocer una manera diferente de obtener el resultado.

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Pues me dijo que ese tipo de consultas no están presentes en los libros y que quien sabe de que página del internet (ya no recuerdo bien todo lo que dijo), pero la consulta funciona, si tienes alguna otra forma sería de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Comment: El hecho de que hayas usado FOO, puede ser un indicador de que se haya copiado de alguna página. Pero si no fue así, me parece que hubo un buen ejercicio de lógica para combinar 2 funciones de agregado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO,AVG(NOTA) 
FROM CONTROL_ESCOLAR.NOTAS 
GROUP BY (NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO) 
ORDER BY AVG(NOTA) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Con `GROUP BY (NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO)` agrupo a cada uno de los alumnos que tienen registro de Notas, después con `AVG(NOTA)` obtengo el promedio de notas de cada grupo creado, es decir, el promedio de calificaciones de cada uno de los alumnos, con `ORDER BY AVG(NOTA)` limito a ordenar cada uno de esos promedios desde el mayor promedio hasta el menor promedio, esto ultimo gracias a la instrucción `DESC`, por ultimo con `LIMIT` se encarga de acortar la cantidad de registros a mostrar en este caso solo mostrará el primer registro que vendría siendo el alumno con el promedio más alto de todos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte pero solo responder con código se considera de baja calidad, una explicación ayudaría a entender mejor tu solución

Answer (score 2):

Empecemos por entender la razón por la cual no le agradó a tu maestro. En este caso, sólo mostraste el promedio, pero no habrá ninguna forma de saber a quien pertenece. Por eso, es importante pensar en toda la fila como una entidad con distintos atributos.

Para poder obtener la fila completa, se utiliza `LIMIT` para definir cuantas filas tendrá el resultado. Pero otro punto importante es que dentro de un resultado (o tabla), no existe un orden definido, por lo mismo hay que utilizar siempre un `ORDER BY` al utilizar `LIMIT`.

También se considera mejor utilizar alias para las columnas y dejar claro que es cada una de ellas. Esos alias, se pueden utilizar en el `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO,
       AVG(NOTA) PROMEDIO
FROM CONTROL_ESCOLAR.NOTAS 
GROUP BY (NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO) 
ORDER BY PROMEDIO DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Por cierto, si llegaras a necesitar el segundo mejor promedio, sólo tendrías que agregar `OFFSET 1` para que salte una fila.

Comment: Buena respuesta Luis+1

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es solo obtener el puntaje final promedio puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT AVG(NOTA) resultado FROM NOTAS 
GROUP BY (NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO) 
ORDER BY resultado DESC LIMIT 1;
```

> Donde `GROUP BY (NUMERO_MATRICULA_ALUMNO)` te da cada promedio por el
>   numero de matricula de alumno, y `ORDER BY resultado DESC ;` Te ordena
>   el resultado de esos promedios poniendo el mayor al principio , y
>   `LIMIT 1` Te permite visualizar solo el primero de la lista o sea la
>   primera fila (*que vendría a ser el promedio mas alto*).